# Google Maps v2 for Android - nullpointer exception on getUISettings

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map fragment on my app... I load it assyncronously through getMapAsync in the SupportMapFragment object.

In the onMapReady function I have the following lines of code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

map = googleMap; // My internal variable that holds the map for other stuff

map.getUISettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Im getting a lot of NullPointerExceptions on this last line... Both on Android 4 and 5... but I'm unable to reproduce this error.

Anyone got any idea on what can be happening?

Comment: Is `googleMap` always passed as an argument into a method like that, or are you using some sort of public variable from elsewhere? If the latter, it's possible that the object was GCed at some point.

Comment: In this minimal example, `map` should never be null on that line.  Can you give more information about the issue, and also show the stack trace?

Comment: @ReinS, this function is always called as a result of the GoogleMaps Framework, when I call the getMapAsync method. So it should never be null!

Comment: God damn... just found one situation that I get the map with mapFragment.getMap().... This should be causing the problem.... @DanielNugent, if this returns null, the best way to go on is to make a mapFragment.getMapAsync(this) request?